# Strange empty brackets in bibliography (natbib, agsm style)

Tags: bibliographies

I started to get indentation with brackets in front of every reference.
How can I remove these?

Here is my code and I use TexShop.

```
\usepackage{natbib}

\bibliography{filename} 
\bibliographystyle{agsm} 
\nocite{*}
```

```
@article{AguilarAguilera2019BIMbasedFF,
  title={BIM-based framework for indoor acoustic conditioning in early stages of design},
  author={Aguilar-Aguilera, Antonio J and De la Hoz-Torres, M.L. and 
Martínez-Aires, M.D. and Ruiz, Diego P.},
  year={2019}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue. Do not forget to add the three bib entries used to your question. We then have not to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Hi @Mensch, thank you for your quick reply! I have added a part of the code and the rest is mostly the same, is this enough information?

Comment: @Lucy No, this is not enough to reproduce the problem. If you put this code into `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}...\end{document}` the bibliography comes out as expected. So there must be something else in your actual document that is causing the problem. You've added the `biblatex` and `biblatex-chicago` tags. Are you loading `biblatex`? You shouldn't be if you're using `natbib`.

Comment: @AlanMunn Thank you for your comment! I am keeping all of my references in a bib file, is it not compatible with natbib?

Comment: No there is nothing wrong with the `.bib` file. But you should make sure you are not using `\usepackage{biblatex}` somewhere in your code. Or if you have more than one `\bibliographystyle` command. Have you looked at the `.blg` file and the `.log` file to see if there are any errors or warnings. But unless you can reproduce the problem here with a minimal document, it will be hard to help you.

Comment: @AlanMunn I see, I'm not using bib latex or multiple styles. I've just checked blg and log files but couldn't find any errors / warnings and I can't find any relevant part in my code other than what I have shared. The thing is, the same code used to work fine, and from some point, this problem started to happen. I will look into my list in bib file I guess... Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: @Lucy Clearly what you've shown us is *not* the relevant part of the code, since that code by itself (if turned into a complete document) works properly. So you need to work on constructing a small example that does show the problem so that we can reproduce it. E.g. what document class are you using? You don't show that in your  code. Often times by trying to make a reproducible example you will discover what the actual problem is by yourself. The problem is unlikely to be found in your `.bib` file.